# How to run multiple different bots at different endpoints within the same project without using skills?

Tags: botframework

Do you know how to add more bots within the same project?
I think it should be possible because of the commend in CoreBot from BotBuilderSample.
[Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkAwf.png)

However I have no idea how to do it.
Have you managed to do it and can share steps that's need to be done to accomplish it?
[startup class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Qkw.png)

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: As Skills were developed for just this purpose, is there a reason you don't want to use them?

Comment: Hi, no there isn't specific reason why I cannot use skills. I was just curious if it is possible because of the comment in core-bot sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining multiple bots in the same project is not possible. You can only attach one implementation to the IBot interface. Additionally when the project is deployed, its URL will only be recognized as one bot. You can extend the capabilities of your bot by adding more controllers but it will still register as a single bot.

If you still want to do this somehow, I'd suggest creating a menu context as the initial response of your bot. Give the user an option of choosing what functionality (different bot) they are going to use. From that point just separate the flows throughout your bot.

Comment: How do you implement that, though? Let's say I have a "Menu" dialog that chooses functionality. That selects a specific "Bot" dialog (which would have its own LUIS and QnA Maker apps) which can then calls "Action Dialogs" (unique to that Bot) as needed. I want to STAY at the Bot Dialog (e.g. send all activities thorough those LUIS and QnA Maker apps) without ever going back to the "Menu" dialog unless I provide some keyword like Main Menu or Start Over. Is this possible? Because I can't get my head around how to KEEP someone in the Bot dialog "forever" after selecting it in the menu.